# Package Stata Enhanced in Sublime Text - not working with Stata 15

Tags: sublimetext3, stata

I am not able to get the package `Stata Enhanced` for `Sublime Text` to work with Stata 15 (on a Mac). I've uninstalled Stata 14 and rebooted, and I also tried to direct `Stata Enhanced` to the application file with User Settings:

```
{
"stata_name": "/Applications/Stata/StataSE.app/Contents/MacOS/stata-se",
"switch_focus_to_stata": false
}
```

Or substituting `stata-se` with `StataSE` in the User Settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in contact with the developer, Andrew Heiss, and together we identified the problem. He has now updated the package with a new version check. So, if you experience problems, try to update the Stata Enhanced package.

**In Sublime Editor do the following:**

Press Command-Shift-P,

start writing Package Control,

select "Package Control: Update Package",

then select Stata Enhanced.